# How to modify the file name of <input type="file"/> with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use this code to modify `input type="file"` file name.

html:

```
<input type="file" id="videoUpload"/>
```

js:

```
var fileName = $("#videoUpload").prop("files")[0].name;

console.log(a) //testA.mp4

$("#videoUpload").prop(("files")[0].name,"myVideo.mp4")
console.log(a) //testA.mp4
```

The file name is not changed,why?

Comment: This smells like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you actually trying to achieve here? Rename a file on the user's disk? Mislead the user by displaying a different filename to the one they picked in the UI? Have a different filename appear in an HTTP POST request when you later upload the file with Ajax? Something else?

Comment: When the files uploaded by different people have the same name, the system is abnormal. I need to add timestamps to distinguish them, so I need to rename the files.

Comment: Do that in the *server-side* code when you save the file. This has the added bonus of preventing people from deliberately overwriting files owned by other people by constructing their own HTTP requests.

Comment: I can't do it on the server side, the business here is more complicated, I can't explain to you in detail, I'm sorry, I can only handle it on the front end.

Comment: You've got a major security vulnerability in the server-side code. You need to fix that. You should fight whatever barriers in the business prevent you from doing it. Fixing it will also solve this problem so you shouldn't try to hack around this problem on the client side instead of fixing the real problem.

Answer (score -1):

What you could do is before the form is submitted, copy the file, rename it and replace it. (assuming your input has `name=inputName`)

```js
yourFormElement.addEventListener("formdata", ({formData}) => {
  const file = formData.inputName.files[0];
  const blob = new Blob([file],{type: file.type});
  const file2 = new File([blob], "foo.bar", {type: blob.type});
  formData.set("inputName", [file2]);
});
```

But as Quentin said, this is something that you usually have to do on the server because anyone can open the devtools do the changes from above and override other users files on the server.